# How to create child inside child in firebase table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to create table A which has child "1" and it will also supposed to have sub children's as "LSUNL84fjMtKKc6rMlB" and "LSUNNauQJSlub-lrIC2".

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Post your code here.

Comment: You've included pictures of code and the JSON tree in your question. Please replace these with the actual code and JSON as text. The JSON you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. When doing this edit, also make sure to include code that shows what `a` and `b` are.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better tell me more. Try to share some code. The answer to this question I can give is that.

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Your Channel Name");
dbRef.child("1").child("1.1").setValue("Sameer");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to create child inside `A` that would be `1`.

Below code will create child inside `A` that would be `1` Then inside it. It will create a unique id for each record.

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference.child("A/1").push(); 
    String push_id = reference.getKey();  //creating unique id here

    //inserting data into Hashmap to store that data
    Map data = new HashMap();
    data.put("name", "my_name");
    data.put("type", "type here");

    //this Hashmap points to location where you want to store above data.
    Map map1 = new HashMap();
    map1.put("A/1/" + push_id, data);

    //updateChildren will create a new child inside your Database or update it, if already exists. 
    reference.updateChildren(map1, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError == null) {

                Toast.makeText(Messages.this, "Data inserted  !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```